# Adding users with role to thread channel using discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to add users with specific role to threads. My code is:

```
    bot.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.content == '?threadref') {    
    let list = message.guild.roles.cache.get('948258030192058410').members.map(m=>m.user.id);
    for (var i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
      const user = list[i-1];
      const thread1 = channel.threads.cache.find(x => x.id === '945763756728787006');
      const thread2 = channel.threads.cache.find(x => x.id === '947100498035638283');
      const thread3 = channel.threads.cache.find(x => x.id === '947100722321846272');
      const thread4 = channel.threads.cache.find(x => x.id === '945763910756204585');
      const thread5 = channel.threads.cache.find(x => x.id === '946785089486987305');
      const thread6 = channel.threads.cache.find(x => x.id === '946784996537012254');
      const thread7 = channel.threads.cache.find(x => x.id === '946784810981023754');
      
      await thread1.members.add(user);
      await thread2.members.add(user);
      await thread3.members.add(user);
      await thread4.members.add(user);
      await thread5.members.add(user);
      await thread6.members.add(user);
      await thread7.members.add(user);
      console.log(`${user} was added to threads`);
    }
  }
});
```

But when i try to use this code i get error:

```
(node:453) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: channel is not defined
(node:453) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:453) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Can someone tell how get channel variable.
I get code from https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/threads.html#adding-and-removing-members and there i can't find what channel mean.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the channel property from your `message` object, say:

```js
  bot.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  let { channel } = message;
  if (message.content == '?threadref') { 
  ...   
}
});

/*
* Alternatively you can use message.channel 
 directly on each time you a define thread. 
* Welcome to stackoverflow! 
*/
```

Comment: now im getting other error 
(node:269) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined

Comment: Make sure those channels have threads

Comment: it still doesn't work ;-; channel.threads is undefined

Comment: console.log(channel.threads)
returns undefined

Comment: Well there you go, you have your error, the channel(s) don't have thread(s) or you're just not having sufficient intents to access them also make sure your djs version is 13 you're using the message event in the code you provided which has been switched to messageCreate